# React Native App Crashes on "--variant=release" command : Signed APK

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

I have been trying to build the Signed APK of an application having simple navigation drawer. I have created the keystore as followed the official react docs. But finally once oi created the bundle i am trying to run "**react-native run-android --variant=release**", it gives a successful build but the app crashes once i open the nav drawer swipe right. But the app works totally fine running with the development server. I even tried **$ cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease** , even then the application crashes at the same point. Can even suggest me how could i fix this , will this be a setup issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bundle all assets but before that delete files inside directory

```
android/app/src/main/assets
```

and then run `$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
and then try to continue with your steps.

Comment: Thanks but i tried that so, that didn't find a solution for the problem which i was facing for. Finally i solved it by importing react-navigation,react-navigation-drawer and react-native-gesture-handler inside index.js and its built successfully !!!
Note : This import should be done before AppRegistry.registerComponent